# Issue in formatting date/numeric columns in SSRS matrix report

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Mine is tablix report, with columns and values. Which are dynamically generating.

[image: SSRS report in Report Builder]

Issue is, there are some date and numeric columns which i want to format, and for that i am trying below given expressions:

```
=IIf(Fields!ColumnName.Value = "Charge",
    FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value, 2),
    IIf(Fields!ColumnName.Value = "StartDate",
        FORMAT(CDate(Fields!Value.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy"),
    IIf(Fields!ColumnName.Value = "EndDate",
        FORMAT(CDate(Fields!Value.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy"),
        Fields!Value.Value
    )
  )
 )
```

OR

```
=Switch
(
  Fields!ColumnName.Value = "Charge", FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value, 2),
  Fields!ColumnName.Value = "StartDate", FORMAT(CDate(Fields!Value.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy"),
  Fields!ColumnName.Value = "EndDate", FORMAT(CDate(Fields!Value.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy"),
  true, Fields!Value.Value
)
```

OR

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Value.Value), FormatNumber(Fields!Value.Value, 2), Fields!Value.Value)
```

none of them are working, it changes the number columns correctly and then it gives #Error in every columns.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following custom code to your report

```
Public Function FormatColumn(columnName As String, value AS String) As String

Select columnName
    Case "Charge" 
        Return  Format(CLng(value), "c2")
    Case "StartDate"
         Return Format(CDate(value),"MM-dd-yyyy")
    Case "EndDate"
         Return Format(CDate(value),"MM-dd-yyyy")
    Case Else  
        Return value
End Select 


End Function
```

Set the cell expression to

```
= Code.FormatColumn(Fields!ColumnName.Value,Fields!value.Value)
```